# How do I route to a different angular page when the window size is below 800px?

Tags: angular, routes, responsive

I am creating an Angular 8 browser that displays a table. Since there are many columns, when that window size is too small, I would like to display a table with less columns that can be expanded downward to show more information. I have both of these different layouts already created in different html files. Is there a way to route to the file with the expanded-rows view once the screen reaches a certain size and then route back to the file with the regular table view when the screen is large enough? How is this done?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wouldn't route to a new page on window resize. I'd listen to the window resize it in your parent component and then use an ngIf or similar to switch between large / small table components. Navigation seems overkill for what is really a deletion / addition of columns on the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so in the parent component to load a suitable child component using [`BreakPointObserver`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview#breakpointobserver) in the following manner.

```
import {BreakpointObserver} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
```

...

```
constructor(private bpo: BreakpointObserver){}
```

...

```
ngOnInit(){

    // Listen to changes in screen width
    this.bpo.observe(['(min-width: 800px)'])
    .subscribe(result => {
        if (result.matches) {
        // Navigate to larger view
        } else {
        // Navigate to smaller view
        }
    });
}
```

Check [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y54pnd) to play around. Change the screen size of the output window to see that `larger` or `smaller` component is loaded accordingly.

**EDIT:**

To `unsubscribe`, you need to store the subscription and unsubscribe on the [subscription](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription), like  -

```
private bpoSubscription: Subscription;
```

....

```
this.bpoSubscription = this.bpo.observe(['(min-width: 800px)'])
                       .subscribe(result => {
                         if (result.matches) {
                         // Navigate to larger view
                         } else {
                         // Navigate to smaller view
                         }
                        });
```

...

```
ngOnDestroy(){
   this.bpoSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Check [this updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfxsgj)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! How do I make it check this page only for the min-width? It is checking all pages and navigating to the smaller view for my other pages that are not related to this table with the different view options.

Comment: If you `unsubscribe` from the listener attached in the `ngOnDestroy` of that particular component, that should do the trick.

Comment: I received this error :              core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ListComponent -> Subscription]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ListComponent -> Subscription]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Subscription!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ListComponent -> Subscription]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ListComponent -> Subscription]:

Comment: Updated in the answer. Check if that works for you @BDev14